# Python: How to match a known character and then varying digits out of a string using regex and create an average of results?

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup, expression

I am new to using Python, regex and BeautifulSoup, I want to have a query to extract the currency and then the digits within the -->   < !-- (not including the pointers though) which can be of different lengths but I also want to ignore any of the potential following:
digits below 100, above 500,000, 123, 1234, 12345, 123456

This is due to trying to get accurate averages of car price listings.
The second one is in pounds, I would like to convert that to euro and list as euro as well if anyone can help with that?

For example, out of the following scraped code..

```
<span data-reactid="1268"><span data-reactid="1269">€</span><!-- react-text: 1270 -->16,500<!-- /react-text --></span>
<span data-reactid="1274"><span data-reactid="1275">£</span><!-- react-text: 1276 -->296<!-- /react-text --></span>
<span data-reactid="1322"><span data-reactid="1323">€</span><!-- react-text: 1324 -->8,950<!-- /react-text --></span>
```

I want to get the following results..

```
16500
355   <-- which I want to be got by multiplying £ figure by 1.2
8950
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
price_list = soup.findAll(class_='card__price')
for price in price_list:
    prices = price.contents[0]
    #prices = re.search("")
    #soup.findAll(re.compile("(...)"))
    print(prices)
```

.. So the final result would just be the average (8602) so I can have that one result to export into a database or whatever I choose to do with it next :D

Comment: The example you gave are the tags *within*  a `price` in `price_list`?

Comment: @wwii I don't understand